# How to recode and create multiple variables from differrent formatted datasets?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, recode

I am working with two different survey datasets conducted in the U.S. (us_data) and in Ukraine (ukr_data).The dataset have respondents evaluating their reaction to different actions politicians can take (labeled Action 1 and Action 2 in the working example below).Respondents evaluated each action across four dimensions:

```
   1) How acceptable they view the action? 
   2) How violent they think the action is?
   3) How threatened they feel by the action?
   4) How disgusted they feel by the action?
```

The measurements of 1-4 were repeated across several actions. The questions asked on both surveys are the exact same but the datasets are in different format. The Ukrainian dataset is in a long format with a variable marking whether respondents are evaluating Action 1 or Action 2. In contrast the U.S. dataset is in a wide format, with different questions for each action on each of the four dimensions.

I'd like to be able to create a new variables and recode the variables as one large function and return the means of each evaluation (acceptable, violent, threatened, and disgusted) for each action (Action 1 and Action 2 in the example) for each country (U.S. and Ukraine), as well the Cronbach's alpha for each four evaluations for each action by country. Since there are 40+ Actions in the actual dataset it would be much preferable to do this as part of a loop.

As an R newbie, I am having some issues since the formatting of the datasets is different, and I am not really sure how to recode the variables in mass.

Below I have provided a minimal working example of the two datasets. I can get this code chunk to work and recode the acceptability of Action 1 and its mean in both the US and Ukraine. But I want to be able to perform a loop that does this for each each action (40 +), all 4 evaluations, and in each country.

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(psych)
> 
> ##Clear the Workspace
> rm(list = ls())
> 
> 
> ##Setting Up the Ukraine data###
> 
> ##Which Action is being addressed
> ukr_actlabels<-c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
> 
> ###Attitudes Towards Actions
> ukr_acceptable<-c(1,6, 2,1, 3,1, 4, 1, 2, 5)
> ukr_violent<-c(2,1, 2,1, 3,1, 4, 7, 2, 3)
> ukr_threat<- c(1,1, 1,1, 3,1, 4, 1, 2, 3)
> ukr_disgusting<- c(1,3, 6,1, 3,1, 3, 1, 2, 4)
> 
> ukr_data<-data.frame(cbind(ukr_actlabels,ukr_acceptable, ukr_violent,          ukr_threat, ukr_disgusting  ))
    > ukr_data
   ukr_actlabels ukr_acceptable ukr_violent ukr_threat ukr_disgusting
1              1              1           2          1              1
2              1              6           1          1              3
3              1              2           2          1              6
4              1              1           1          1              1
5              1              3           3          3              3
6              2              1           1          1              1
7              2              4           4          4              3
8              2              1           7          1              1
9              2              2           2          2              2
10             2              5           3          3              4
> 
> ###US data 
> ##Attitudes Towards Action 1
> us_a1_acceptable<-c(3,1, 4, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
> us_a1_violent<-c(2,1, 2, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
> us_a1_threat<-c(2,1, 5, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
> us_a1_disgusting<-c(2,1, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
> 
> ##For Action 2
> ##Attitudes Towards action 2
> us_a2_acceptable<-c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3,1, 4, 2, 5)
> us_a2_violent<-c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2,1, 2, 1, 2)
> us_a2_threat<-c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2,1, 5, 1, 3)
> us_a2_disgusting<-c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2,1, 3, 3, 4)
> 
> us_data<-data.frame(cbind(us_a1_acceptable,us_a1_violent, us_a1_threat,     us_a1_disgusting, us_a2_acceptable,us_a2_violent, us_a2_threat,     us_a2_disgusting))
> us_data
   us_a1_acceptable us_a1_violent us_a1_threat us_a1_disgusting     us_a2_acceptable us_a2_violent
1                 3             2            2                2                       NA            NA
2                 1             1            1                1                NA            NA
3                 4             2            5                3               NA            NA
4                 1             1            1                3               NA            NA
5                 2             2            1                3               NA            NA
6                NA            NA           NA               NA                    3             2
7                NA            NA           NA               NA                1             1
8                NA            NA           NA               NA                4             2
9                NA            NA           NA               NA                2             1
10               NA            NA           NA               NA                5             2
   us_a2_threat us_a2_disgusting
1            NA               NA
2            NA               NA
3            NA               NA
4            NA               NA
5            NA               NA
6             2                2
7             1                1
8             5                3
9             1                3
10            3                4
> 
> ##How acceptable is Action 1 in Ukraine?####
> 
> ##Creating a new variable for acceptable filled with NAs
> ukr_data$act1_acceptable<-NA
> 
> ###Substituting the previous values of ukr_acceptable if 
> ukr_data$act1_acceptable<-ifelse(ukr_data$ukr_actlabels==1,     ukr_data$ukr_acceptable, NA)
> table(ukr_data$act1_acceptable)

1 2 3 6 
2 1 1 1 
> 
> ###Reocding so #1=Never, 2= Rarely, 3= Sometimes, 4=Very Often, 5=Always
> ukr_data$act1_acceptable<-recode(ukr_data$act1_acceptable,`1`=5, `2`=4,     `3`=3, `4`=2, `5`=1)
> table(ukr_data$act1_acceptable)

3 4 5 6 
1 1 2 1 
> 
> ##Recoding the missing values of 6 and 7 to NA
> ukr_data$act1_acceptable[ukr_data$act1_acceptable ==6 | ukr_data$act1_acceptable ==7] <- NA 
> table(ukr_data$act1_acceptable)

3 4 5 
1 1 2 
> 
> ###How acceptable is Action 1 in the US?
> table(us_data$us_a1_acceptable)

1 2 3 4 
2 1 1 1 
> 
> 
> ###Creating a new variable 
> ###Reocding so #1=Never, 2= Rarely, 3= Sometimes, 4=Very Often, 5=Always
> us_data$act1_acceptable<-recode(us_data$us_a1_acceptable,`1`=5, `2`=4,     `3`=3, `4`=2, `5`=1)
> 
> 
> table(us_data$act1_acceptable)

2 3 4 5 
1 1 1 2 
> 
> 
> ####Returning the mean
> 
> mean(ukr_data$act1_acceptable, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 4.25
> 
> mean(us_data$act1_acceptable, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 3.8
```

What I'd like to do is have the loop return the following information. For each action (Action 1 to Action 43, I have 43 in my actual dataset). I'd like a loop to return for each action:

```
        1) Mean Acceptability of the Action in the US
        2) Mean Acceptability of the Action in Ukraine
        3) Mean Perception of Violence of the Action in US
        4) Mean Perception of Violence of the Action in Ukraine 
        5) Mean Threat of the Action in US
        6) Mean Threat of the Action in Ukraine
        7) Mean Disgust of the Action in the US
        8) Mean Disgust of the Action in Ukraine
        9)Cronbach's Alpha of Acceptable, Violence, Threat, and Disgust for Action in the US
        10) Cronbach's Alpha of Acceptable, Violence, Threat, and Disgust for Action in Ukraine
```

I do have a spreadsheet listing which labels (Ukraine dataset) and questions (US) dataset correspond to which action.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Typically a good first step would be to match the format of both data sets. I'd recommend converting the US data to long format, then you can combine the data into a single data frame, and add tags for US/Ukraine data. then simple group-wise operations will get you all the summary stats you're looking for.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks.